# "Built-in port forwarding" error after Visual Studio Code update

Tags: perl, visual-studio-code

After the latest Visual Studio Code update, my Perl extension fails with the output:

```
""C:\StrawberryPerl\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-d" "X:\Perl\a.pl""
Unable to connect to remote host: localhost:57937
Compilation failed in require.
 at X:\Perl\a.pl line 0.
        main::BEGIN() called at X:\Perl\a.pl line 0
        eval {...} called at X:\Perl\a.pl line 0
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
 at X:\Perl\a.pl line 0.
```

I'm sure the reason is the new "[Built-in port forwarding](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_82#_workbench)". I think, my [Perl extension](https://github.com/raix/vscode-perl-debug/blob/master/readme.old.md) uses port 5000, but my VSC settings.json doesn't contain a line `"port": 5000`:

```
{
    "launch": {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
            "type": "perl",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Perl-Debug local",
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "program": "${file}",
            "exec": "C:\\StrawberryPerl\\perl\\bin\\perl.exe",
            "execArgs": [],
            "root": "${workspaceRoot}/",
            "inc": [],
            "args": [],
            "env": {},
            "debugRaw": false,
            "debugLog": false,
            "stopOnEntry": false,
                "sessions": "single"
            }
          ],
       "compounds": []
    },
    "terminal.external.windowsExec": "X:\\Perl\\vsc_cmd.cmd",
"workbench.editor.tabSizing": "shrink",
"editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
}
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Can I undo the "Built-in port forwarding"?

Comment: The [perl-debug](https://github.com/raix/vscode-perl-debug) vscode extension seems to be deprecated, have you tried other vscode extensions like [Perl-LanguageServer](https://github.com/richterger/Perl-LanguageServer)? If you do not need debugging support I can also recommend [PerlNavigator](https://github.com/bscan/PerlNavigator)

Comment: I tried other extensions as well, this was the only one that worked without the weirdest errors possible. Even though it is deprecated, I still would like to be able to use it... @Codr if you find an answer please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a few options. You could use Windows Subsystem for Linux, where this extension (the Raix debugger) still works in the manner you have described. Port forwarding must be handled differently in WSL. The Perl::LanguageServer debugger works in WSL as well.

If you want to continue using the Raix debugger in native Windows, the following configuration also worked for me in the latest version of vscode. Add these lines to your launch.json:

```
"sessions": "watch",
"console": "remote",
"port": 5000,
```

Then when you launch the debugger, it will run in "watch" mode, waiting for a Perl process to connect to the extension. To run a script that will connect, you can use something like this:

```
cmd /C "set "PERLDB_OPTS=RemotePort=localhost:5000" && perl -d C:\Path\myScript.pl "
```

The extension authors also recommend you use `Devel::vscode` when running in this way, but I have not tested that. I also generally recommend using the Perl Navigator for language server support (I'm the maintainer), especially when running in Windows. Long term, I would like to add debugger support to the Navigator, while continuing to support Windows.